# Anybody have the XSD for XMLSS?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

Anybody have the XSD for XMLSS?

I'd like to change from an excel binary format to a format that can be merged using subversion. I'm hoping the Excel 2003 XML format would work and allow edits via Excel.